# Passing html code from views to template in Django

Tags: django-templates, django-views

I have an html-table generated in views.py. I want to show it in my html template. If I pass the html code as a string, symbols like "<" are automatically substituted to "& lt;", so instead of the table I see its html code. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 17):

Just have to escape html var with `|safe` filter as follows

**In your views.py**

```
....
context['your_html_variable '] = "<div><h1> Hello </h1></div>"
return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

**In your template.html**

```
<body>
    {{ your_html_variable|safe }}
</body>
```

## Be Careful ! Never try to escape html variable when it comes from user, not you.